# Is there a way to configure Prettier so that it doesn't minify inline CSS in .mjml templates?

Tags: prettier, mjml, prettier-vscode

I'm using [`.mjml`](https://mjml.io/) templates and VSCode. I had to install an extension for the highlighting to work correctly but I noticed by Prettier seems to transform inline CSS (which is pretty common in emails) from this:

```css
p,
h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
h1,
.text-h1 h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

to this:

```css
p, h1 { color: #ffffff; } h1, .text-h1 h1 { font-size: 32px; line-height: 1.1; margin: 0 0 16px 0; font-weight: 700; }
```

The only way I was able to prevent this is by adding a `<!-- prettier-ignore -->` before the `<mj-style>` tag but I was wondering if there isn't a better way (configuration?) to get the same result without the extra markup.

See:

- https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/issues/2557
- [Is there a way to tell Prettier that the following "block" has a specific markup type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73940984/is-there-a-way-to-tell-prettier-that-the-following-block-has-a-specific-markup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research and also the lack of answers, it looks like the overall MJML tooling ecosystem is not in the best of states. I think for now the **best option is to use the workaround I provided**. Here is a detailed breakdown of the options available.

**Style element `<mj-style>`:** (most likely the best option)

```html
<!-- prettier-ignore -->
<mj-style css-inline="inline" />  
  .content {
     color: green !important;
  }
</mj-style>
```

- **Pros**:

  - Works in the [online visual editor](https://mjml.io/try-it-live) by copy/pasting the markup.
- **Cons**:

  - No Prettier formatting ([ref](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/9191)).

**An external CSS file:**

```html
<mj-include path="./default.css" type="css" css-inline="inline" />
```

- **Pros**:

  - You can import a CSS file that will get normal Prettier treatment.
  - Standard pattern where CSS lives outside the document.
- **Cons**:

  - It also won't work with the [online MJML editor tool](https://mjml.io/try-it-live) without merging back your CSS file. This is very annoying and makes it hard to maintain.
  - `<mj-include>` can report miss flagged error depending on our your project is setup.
  - It does not work with the "official" VSCode plugin (you have to use [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanielKnights.vscode-mjml)).

**MJML inline styles:**

```html
<mj-text color="#fff" padding="0" font-weight="400" font-size="16px" line-height="1.65" />
```

- **Pros**:

  - You don't need CSS.
- **Cons**:

  - You possibly will repeat a lot of the same style and maintenance can become problematic.

**Style element `<mj-class>`:**

```html
<mj-class name="blue" color="blue" />
```

**Pros:**

- Benefits from the re-usability of CSS without having to use CSS, avoiding Prettier issues.

**Cons:**

- Not as flexible as CSS in terms of selectors which can lead to repetition and maintenance issues.